# Why ifconfig and airmon-ng show me a different result?

Tags: aircrack-ng

[image: Screenshot]

I can see encryption details and AUTH types with ifconfig but not airmon-ng.
Do I need to do something about it in order to to get better results from

- Fake authentication attack
- ARP request attack
- Deauthentication attack

I couldn't change wlan0 to wlan0mon either, but I used ifconfig instead, and I could manage to do those attacks. (I've never succeeded cracking yet, so I am blaming ifconfig and myself)

I use

- AWUS036AC
- Host: MacOS
- Guest VM: Linux 5.7.0 amd64 kali

Comment: Are these screenshots changed in any way? ifconfig on its own is definitely not used to scan for SSIDs. That looks like it's the output of airodump-ng. The screenshot on the left is also not the output of starting monitor mode. Something is strange, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: thank you for the input. I did screenshot carelessly, I'll try to make a new screenshot again!!!

Comment: I changed to monitor mode with using
'iw dev wlan0 set type monitor'
instead of airmon,

Comment: I changed to monitor mode with using
iw dev wlan0 set type monitor instead of airmon according to my memo, but now I can't use it. It says command failed: No such device (-19)
 It seems like I did wrong from the beginning, I will try from the start again :D

Comment: I think you are trying to do your demo tasks too fast and not learning the essentials along the way. I suggest you start slowly verifying each step. Familiarise yourself with ifconfig / iwconfig and use them to verify Kali is able to detect your wifi card (likely would register as wlan0). Only then consider placing it in monitor mode.

Comment: you are exactly right, I just copied and pasted from demo videos and articles though, I decided to start from the beginning of the beginning after many errors that I don't even understand. Thanks for the input by the way :)